# Equilibrium equations. Clarification.

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Please help me to correct my understanding:

$$C^{-1}y+Ax=b \\
A^Ty  =f$$

$C^{-1}+Ax=b$ represents Ohm's law, derived from $e=b-Ax$.  Vector x represent potential on each node in a graph, on each node present abstract force which **repel** abstract flow. Flow goes to lower potential (which repel less). Act of multiplication $Ax$ produces potential difference. I just add all columns vectors adjusted by corresponding potential on each node, this is certainly should give me potential differences on each edge. But formula telling me: $Ax=b-e$. This is my problem. What $e$ stands for? I know $b$ - potential differences, i can find potential at each node, i now x i can find differences. What does $e$ mean? In another words if i know potential at each node $C^{-1}y=Ax$? Thank you.

Comment: I think you should have a circuit when you were tought this formula.  Can you share?

Comment: This is question about equilibrium in any graph it is not related to particular circuit. This formulas come from Gilbert Strang books. I really need to understand what is e. Shame nobody knows.